# How to indent an object using edge loops without changing edge sharpness?

Tags: mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

I am trying to make a small indent in the bottom of a gun I am modelling, like in the picture below.[image]

The problem is, in order to add this indent, I need to add detail to my mesh, in the form of more vertices. These additional vertices change the sharpness of the bottom of the barrel by affecting my subsurface modifier, making the edge too sharp where the indentation is.

Is there a way I can both have my indentation at that height, and keep the edge at the desired sharpness?
I know such a small detail is unimportant, but feel it is important to learn.
I have tried three methods.

tl;dr- I tried a boolean modifier, moving my edge loops away from the bottom edge where I didn't need them for the indent, and using vertices without edge loops. The first resulted in unrealistic sharpness in the indent. The other two made the bottom edge unevenly rounded.

[image]

The above indent was made with a Boolean modifier. As you can see, the inner edges are rounded, which I achieved by making the 'cutting' object rounded here. But because the bottom edge of the barrel is curved inwards, I cannot make the 'cutting' object match this curve without applying a ton of modifiers and unnecessary complexity which will slow my render.
The result is that the outer edges, marked in red, have unrealistic perfect 90 degree turns.

[image]

Here I used edge loops add the necessary geometry for an indentation. The point is, even if I move other parts of the edge loop, the edge was still too sharp at the indentation itself, because the vertices making the indentation also sharpen the edge. 
Adding vertices without edge loops has the same problem, but also creates ngons.

Comment: My guess is you added details cut before line out your basic shape, can you share your model please? And link to your tutorial (if there is any).